# I can't execute data-load (Symfony 1.4 Doctrine)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, fixtures, data-dump

I have a some problem with my symfony project.
I have a MySQL database with InnoDB tables.
I try to create simple tree-menu:

schema.yml

```
Menu:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        disabled: true
      updated:
        disabled: true
  columns:
    id: { type: integer, autoincrement: true, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    parent: { type: integer, notnull: false }
  relations:
    Parent:
      alias: parentItem
      foreignAlias: childrens
      class: Menu
      local: parent
      foreign: id
      type: many-to-one
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

After creating elements in backend I execute `data:dump` and get this code

fixture:

```
Menu:
  Menu_1:
    name: 'Parent'
  Menu_2:
    parentItem: Menu_1
    name: 'Children'
```

If I try to run, I have lost the relations between the items

I do not understand what's wrong.

**Edit:**

Before:

```
| id | name     | parent |
| 1  | Parent   | NULL   |
| 2  | Children | 1      |
```

After

```
| id | name     | parent |
| 1  | Parent   | NULL   |
| 2  | Children | 0      |
```

Comment: What do you mean by *lost relations*?

Comment: @j0k
Before: 

`| id | name     | parent |`
`| 1  | Parent   | NULL   |`
`| 2  | Children | 1      |`

After

`| id |   name   | parent |`
`| 1  |  Parent  |  NULL  |`
`| 2  | Children |    0   |`

Comment: @j0k sory. I lost a a value in parent-col. It becomes a 0

Comment: Well for me, every thing seems ok since you reference the relation using `parentItem` and the key for the parent. Strange..

Comment: @j0k I tried to use parent. no changes. (

Answer (score 1):

I think the relations' type is one, the relations' foreignType is many:

```
Menu:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        disabled: true
      updated:
        disabled: true
  columns:
    id: { type: integer, autoincrement: true, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    parent: { type: integer, notnull: false }
  relations:
    Parent:
      alias: parentItem
      class: Menu
      local: parent
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignAlias: childrens
      foreignType: many
      onDelete: CASCADE
```